# Android WifiDirect GO negotiation

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have 2 questions regarding the android implementation of wifiDirect:

1. Assuming that i have 2 devices A and B. Once A initiates a connection to B, i can supply a groupOwnerIntent to A. But how i can set a groupOwnerIntent to the device B? And then the device with higher groupOwnerIntent will become a group owner.
2. Assuming that i can supply for every single device a groupOwnerIntent ( and not only for the device that initiate the connection), if i have 3 devices A, B and C. Let's say that A and B are in the same group and A is a group Owner. And then i want to connect A to C. If C have a higher groupOwnerIntent than A, will A and B become peers of C?

Thanks!

Comment: `for the device that initiate the connection)`. Which one is that in your scenario?

Comment: @greenapps it doesn't matter who initiate the connection if i can supply a groupOwnerIntent for every single device, right?

Comment: Dont know. But then why are you naming it?

Comment: @greenapps do you have any idea if i can have groupOwnerIntent for multiple devices?

Comment: No. I have not a single idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. No, since there is existing group already. C will simply make connection only to the A and A stays as GO. There would not be re-negotiations of exiting groups. If you break the group first, and start forming it again, then of course the GO can go to other device as well.